# Error comes when importing a audio file to Unity 2020.1

Tags: unity-game-engine, audio, import

When I importing a audio file (mp3) to unity (2020.1.6f1) this error comes.

**Unknown platform passed to AudioImporter.ContainsSampleSettingsOverride (WSA), please use one of 'Web', 'Standalone', 'iOS', 'Android', 'WebGL', 'PS4', 'XboxOne' or 'WSA'**

Comment: This is a new bug currently found in newer version of Unity. And seems to be working fine in older version. Current know fix is to add Audio Source component to the game object. Then drag and dropped the audio file to that Audio Source component. Then use that component in your script.

Comment: Yeah it worked for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

My fix was just uninstalling and then re-installing Unity this time making sure NOT to install the Universal Windows Platform build support. I opened the project again and this error was gone including any problems with additional .wav or .mp3 files being added. If you don't need to release on the UWP, then this might be a working solution.

Answer (score 0):

I set up all settings in Universal Windows Platform according to my system and this error has gone after relaunch Unity. It seems you can fix that without reinstalling.[Build settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CCxRi.jpg)